# How to register two occluded images

Tags: image, registration, occlusion

I have two mult view occluded images such as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJKWw.jpg) - reference image and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fktR.jpg)- sense images.

These images are multiview- translatin and rotation images. I want to registe of two images. When I have registered these two images using finding features poits using SURF and apply homography matrixa and registered two images, my output result is not perfect.

I did not get real registered images. How can I register these two images in these occluded region?

Note:- I did not have camera calibration details.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My output result of two occluded images is as:
[image]